# How do I get rid of the vertical stripes in my spectrogram?

Tags: java, audio, fft, spectrogram

Within the scope of a paper I am writing at high school I chose to make my own audio-file-to-spectrogram-converter from scratch in order to create landscapes out of these spectrograms.

I already do have my implementation of an FFT and of using that to make a heightmap, a spectrogram. But I often get weird artifacts in the form of vertical stripes when the frequencies get dense, as you can see in the image below.

[image: Spectrogram of Mozart's Requiem, Lacrimosa]

The example is right at the beginning with a window length of 2048 and on a log^2-scale. The FFT I am using is flawless, I've already compared it to others and they produce the same result.

This is the function which transforms the amplitudes into frequencies and stores them in a 2D-array:

```
private void transform(int from, int until) {
    double val, step;
    for(int i=from; i<until; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            chunk[j] = data[0][i*n+j+start];

        fft.realForward(chunk);

        for(int j=0; j<height; j++) {
            val = Math.sqrt(chunk[2*j]*chunk[2*j] + chunk[2*j+1]*chunk[2*j+1]);
            map[i][j] = val;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my Question: **Where do these vertical stripes come from** and how do I get rid of them?

I currently don't employ a window function and every calculation is stringed to one another, which means there is no overlapping. It is the simplest way you can think of making a spectrogram. Could it help **introducing a window function** or doing each calculation independent of whether the frame was already involved in a previous calculation, that is to say **overlapping the frame-windows**?

Also, what other ways are there to improve on my basic approach in order to get a better result?

This is the whole class. I feed it the data and all the necessary information from an audio file:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D;

public class Heightmap extends JFrame implements WindowListener{
    public static final int LOG_SCALE = 0;
    public static final int LOG_SQUARE_SCALE = 1;
    public static final int SQUARE_SCALE = 2;
    public static final int LINEAR_SCALE = 3;

    private BufferedImage heightmap;
    private FileDialog chooser; 

    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu fileMenu;
    private JMenuItem save, close;

    private DoubleFFT_1D fft;
    private int[][] data;
    private double[][] map;
    private double[] chunk;
    private int width, height, n, start, scale;
    private String name;

    private boolean inactive;

    public Heightmap(int[][] data, int resolution, int start,
            int width, int height, int scale, String name) {

        this.data = data;
        this.n = resolution;
        this.start = start;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.name = name;

        fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(n);
        map = new double[width][height];
        heightmap = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        chunk = new double[n];      

        System.out.println("Starting transformation...");

        long time;
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        transform();
        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        System.out.println("Time taken for calculation: "+time+" ms");

        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        makeHeightmap();
        initComponents();
        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        System.out.println("Time taken for drawing heightmap: "+time+" ms");

    }

    private void initComponents() {
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setTitle(name);

        createMenuBar();
        chooser = new FileDialog(this, "Choose a directory", FileDialog.SAVE);
        chooser.setDirectory("/Users/<user>/Desktop");

        this.addMouseListener(new HeightmapMouseListener());
        this.addKeyListener(new HeightmapKeyListener());
        this.addWindowListener(this);

        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void createMenuBar() {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new JMenu();

        fileMenu.setText("File");

        save = new JMenuItem("Save...", KeyEvent.VK_S);
        save.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.META_DOWN_MASK));
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                chooser.setVisible(true);

                String fileName = chooser.getFile();
                String dir = chooser.getDirectory();
                chooser.setDirectory(dir);

                if(fileName != null) {
                    try {
                        File outputfile = new File(dir + fileName + ".png");
                        ImageIO.write(heightmap, "png", outputfile);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Saved "+fileName+".png to "+dir);
                }
            }
        });

        close = new JMenuItem("Close", KeyEvent.VK_C);
        close.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, InputEvent.META_DOWN_MASK));
        close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
                dispose();
            }
        });

        fileMenu.add(save);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(close);

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(heightmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    private void transform() {
        transform(0, width);
    }
    private void transform(int from, int until) {
        double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double val, step;
        for(int i=from; i<until; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                chunk[j] = data[0][i*n+j+start];
            }
            fft.realForward(chunk);

            for(int j=0; j<height; j++) {
                val = Math.sqrt(chunk[2*j]*chunk[2*j] + chunk[2*j+1]*chunk[2*j+1]);

                if(val > max)
                    max = val;
                if(val < min)
                    min = val;
                map[i][j] = val;
            }

            if(min != 0) {
                step = max/(max-min);
                for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
                    map[i][j] = (map[i][j]-min)*step;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Paints heightmap into the BufferedImage
     */
    private void makeHeightmap() {
        double max = 0;
        switch(scale) {
        case LOG_SCALE: max = Math.log(findMax(map)+1); break;
        case LOG_SQUARE_SCALE: max = Math.pow(Math.log(findMax(map)+1), 2); break;
        case SQUARE_SCALE: max = Math.sqrt(findMax(map)); break;
        case LINEAR_SCALE: max = findMax(map); break;
        default: max = Math.pow(Math.log(findMax(map)+1), 2); break;
        }
        double stepsize = 255.0/max;
        int val, rgb;

        for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
            for(int y=0; y<height; y++) {
                switch(scale) {
                case LOG_SCALE: val = (int) (Math.log(map[x][y]+1)*stepsize); break;
                case LOG_SQUARE_SCALE: val = (int) (Math.log(map[x][y]+1)*stepsize); val *= val; break;
                case SQUARE_SCALE: val = (int) (Math.sqrt(map[x][y])*stepsize); break;
                case LINEAR_SCALE: val = (int) (map[x][y]*stepsize); break;
                default: val = (int) (Math.log(map[x][y]+1)*stepsize); val *= val; break;
                }
                rgb = 255<<24 | val<<16 | val<<8 | val;
                heightmap.setRGB(x, height-y-1, rgb);
            }

    }

    private double findMax(double[][] data) {
        double max = 0;
        for(double[] val1: data)
            for(double d: val1)
                if(d > max)
                    max = d;
        return max;
    }

    private class HeightmapKeyListener implements KeyListener {
        boolean busy = false;

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !busy && start < data[0].length-width*n) {
                busy = true;

                for(int x=0; x<width-1; x++)
                    map[x] = map[x+1].clone();

                start += n;
                transform(width-1, width);              
                makeHeightmap();
                repaint();
                busy = false;
            }
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && !busy && start > 0) {
                busy = true;

                for(int x=width-1; x>0; x--)
                    map[x] = map[x-1];

                start -= n;
                transform(0, 1);
                makeHeightmap();
                repaint();
                busy = false;
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   }
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {  }
    }

    private class HeightmapMouseListener implements MouseListener {


        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(inactive) {
                inactive = false;
                return;
            }

            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            int posX = e.getX();
            int diff = posX - width/2;  //difference between old and new center in pixels
            int oldStart = start;

            start = start + diff*n;
            if(start < 0) start = 0;
            int maxFrame = data[0].length-width*n;
            if(start > maxFrame) start = maxFrame;
            if(start == oldStart) return;

            System.out.println("Changing center...");

            int absDiff = Math.abs(diff);
            if(start < oldStart) {  //shift the start backward, recalculate the start
                for(int x=width-1; x>=absDiff; x--)
                    map[x] = map[x-absDiff].clone();
                transform(0, absDiff);
            }
            else if(start > oldStart) { //shift the back forward, recalculate the back
                for(int x=0; x<width-absDiff; x++)
                    map[x] = map[x+absDiff].clone();
                transform(width-absDiff, width);
            }

            makeHeightmap();
            repaint();
            System.out.println("Time taken: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)+" ms");

        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {    }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {   }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {    }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
    }

    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) { }
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {    }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {   }
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
        inactive = true;
    }
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {   }
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) { }
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {    }

}
```

EDIT:
Implementing a window function improved the result drastically. I really didn't understand what a window function would do and therefore underestimated its effect.

However, after doing so I tried mapping a cosine wave with a frequency of 10kHz which (again) produced some strange artifacts:
[image]

What could be the cause of this one? I implemented a overflow protection by clipping everything under 0 to 0 and over 255 to 255 with no change whatsoever.

Comment: Without code to look at, it's difficult to tell what might be wrong. Can you post a working example demonstrating this behaviour? It might help track down the problem.

Comment: Please add the code you use to generate the image. Maybe add some examples of input/output of the FFT (you say it works flawless, we're not sure because you are so sure). Lastly, it would be better to test your FFT by transforming it back to the audio you are investigating. It should be the same. If it is not, then your FFT is the problem.

Comment: I highlighted the code which actually does the transformation and added the whole class as well. I apologize for the messy and poorly commentated code. I doubt there's anything wrong with the code itself but rather in my method of calculating the data.

Comment: I'll try writing a class for testing the algorithm itself, but the reason I'm so confident is, because I have it from a approved source and because I have tried different sources with the same result. (I'm using [JTransforms](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwiVx4bYnvDIAhXB2Q4KHYhdAcI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fsite%2Fpiotrwendykier%2Fsoftware%2Fjtransforms&usg=AFQjCNFvm1k26Qth54gNrlAl8oMGQABT2Q&sig2=qj3kcJWBDUhegBAlKhYLGw) at the moment)

Comment: You need to apply a window.When there is a discontinuity between the last and first sample you input into the fft then you can expect to see these kinds of artifacts because you are essentially performing an FFT of an impulse and the frequency response of an impulse spreads across the entire spectrum.

Comment: The new added example is the result of a cosine wave with a frequency of 10kHz. A window is applied this time, but there are indeed some strange artifacts left.
Should I maybe just dump the whole eclipse-project somewhere so you could look at it?

Answer (score 1):

This type of artifact can be due to overflow or otherwise exceeding parameter bounds before or in your color mapping function, or perhaps with some function (log?) returning NaN values.  You might be able to find this by putting in some asserts for out-of-range or illegal values.

Comment: I tried simply clipping the color values to 0 or 255 respectively with no change whatsoever. While applying a window of course helped a great deal, there are still some artifacts left that I have no idea where they come from.